# Link field with Browse Server button

Tags: 7, navigation

Is it possible to add the Browse Server button on [Link Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/link)? So user can link to and see internal file or image? I have tried the [Linkit](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit) module, but that is not really what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) module.

> IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal
>   directories and quota.
>
> Features
>
> - Basic file operations: upload, delete
> - Image(jpg, png, gif) operations: resize, create thumbnails, preview
> - Support for private file system
> - Configurable limits for user roles: file size per upload, directory quota, file extensions, and image dimensions
> - Personal or shared folders for users
> - Permissions per directory
> - Ftp-like directory navigation
> - File sorting by name, size, dimensions, date
> - Tabbed interface for file operations
> - Keyboard shortcuts(up, down, insert(or enter), delete, home, end, ctrl+A, R(esize), T(humbnails), U(pload)).
> - Built-in support for inline image/file insertion into textareas
> - Multiple file selection(using ctrl or shift)
> - Ajax file operations
> - Themable layout using tpl files

Comment: Ty @darol100. The site has IMCE, but it does not support the Link field.

Comment: That sucks, I did not realize that. I would recommend you to re-open this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/916076 and ask for D7 support. According to that issue this been fix for D6.

Comment: that page you show is actually the Link inside the CKeditor, not the Link Field in content type.